# Why am I not getting a proper index on pulling df.index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Instead of the index values I get a sort of iteration.

I have a dataframe.
I slice that dataframe.
I then convert that dataframe to numpy array in order to extract the unique values from the slice.
I then convert the numpy array back to a dataframe.
I then run a for loop to extract the index of the values of the original dataframe slice which correspond to the unique values.
I get strange behaviour.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsm')
v =  (df.loc[:, 'test'].values)
g = np.unique(v, return_index=True)
v2 = pd.DataFrame(g)

for v2 in df.loc[:, 'test']:
    print (df.index)
```

The strange behaviour I was talking about:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=14465, step=1)
```

I get 14465 lines of the above. But no Index value

Sample DataFrame

```
test   age
0      17 - Alpha OH PROGESTERONE - HORMONE ASSAYS  23.0
1      17 - Alpha OH PROGESTERONE - HORMONE ASSAYS  26.0
2                    17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  18.0
3                    17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  18.0
4                    17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  21.0
5                    17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  25.0
6                    17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  27.0
7                      24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  32.0
8                      24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  43.0
9                      24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  52.0
10                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  53.0
11                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  56.0
12                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  57.0
13                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  57.0
14                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  57.0
15                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  58.0
16                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  62.0
17                     24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE  85.0
18                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN   3.0
19                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN   5.0
20                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN   5.0
21                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  16.0
22                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  25.0
23                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  27.0
24                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  28.0
25                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  32.0
26                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  32.0
27                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  32.0
28                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  33.0
29                        24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN  34.0
```

Ouput should be something like this:

```
[0:1]
[2:6]
[7:17]
[18:29]
```

Comment: please post a sample dataframe which we can copy paste to replicate this, also post the expected output just to be clear. Thanks

Comment: What do you want? First Index of each group with the last index?

Comment: yes. That's right!

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** More accurate solution is now posted with respect to the new variations of the OP's problem statement. I'm keeping this solution up as just another reference for future.

---

If you only want to extract the first index of the uniques, maybe you want to try **drop_duplicates** instead?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x': ['does', 'this', 'index', 'solve', 'anything', 'your', 'what', 'issue?'], 
        'y': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'e']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('x')
print (df)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Now to get indexes of unique **y**,

```
unique = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['y'], keep='first')
unique.index
```

Gives:

```
Index(['does', 'this', 'solve', 'your', 'issue?'], dtype='object', name='x')
```

​
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use:

```
df.drop_duplicates('test').combine_first(df.drop_duplicates('test',keep='last'))
```

---

```
                                        test   age
0  17 - Alpha OH PROGESTERONE - HORMONE ASSAYS  23.0
1  17 - Alpha OH PROGESTERONE - HORMONE ASSAYS  26.0
2                17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  18.0
6                17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE  27.0
......................
.....................
```

*Another possible solution with [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):*

```
df.groupby('test')['test'].apply(lambda x:[ x.index[0],x.index[-1]])
```

---

```
test
17 - Alpha OH PROGESTERONE - HORMONE ASSAYS      [0, 1]
17 ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERONE                    [2, 6]
24 hrs URINE FOR CREATININE                     [7, 17]
24 hrs URINE FOR PROTEIN                       [18, 29]
```

Comment: performing sort_values() before defining a range of indexes would be a better approach, assuming OP needs a range of indexes.

Comment: @YashNag groupby will take care of that assuming the index is sorted. what say?

Comment: @anki_91 Yes I totally overlooked it. It will take care of it indeed. Thanks for the clarification.